# Calculating $P(X>3)$ where $X$ is the number of throws

Tags: probability

I have the following problem:

> You keep throwing a fair 8-faced die until you obtain an outcome that you already have obtained in one of the previous throws. Let $X$ be the number of throws. Example: if you throw 1, 3,2,3 then $X = 4$. Compute $P(X>3)$.

I will show you what I have so far:

P(X>3) = 1 - P(X=0) - P(X=1) - P(X=2) - P(X=3)

Since P(X=0) and P(X=1) are both 0, I focus on  P(X=2) and P(X=3).

P(X=2):

There are 8*2 = 64 possible combinations. The odds that you thow a certain number is 1/8. So there will be 8 combinations with a double digit. So the odds that P(X=2) = 8/64 = 1/8

P(X=3):

There are 8*3 = 512 combinations possible, but since you the double digit numbers don't count anymore you have 512-8 = 504 options.

Imagine:

1,2
1,3
1,4
1,5
1,6
1,7
1,8

The odds that I make a combination with a double digit is 2/8 = 1/4. So per column I will have 2 combinations with double digits and I have 8 rows. That means that I will have 16 double digit combinations.

16/504 = 0.0317

My final anwswer is 1 - 0.125 - 0.0317 = 0.84

The correct answer is 21/32 = 0.66

What do I do wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, what's the question?  Are you trying to compute the expected number of tosses it takes to see the first duplicate? Something else?

Comment: Hi, the question is what is P(X>3). So I need to calculate the probability that it takes more than 3 throws to reach a duplicate

Comment: Ok.  So $P(X=1)=0$, as you remark.  Can you see that $P(X=2)=\frac 18$?

Comment: Yes, so far have I gotten. But I have really much trouble with P(X=3)

Comment: This is closely related to the birthday paradox. Hint : It is easier to calculate the probability that we have no duplicates after $k$ throws.

Comment: In order to take exactly three tosses, the second toss must differ from the first (what probability is that?) AND the third must be one of the first two (what probability is that?).

Comment: I know that on the first toss it doesn't matter what you throw, on the second toss, you have a 1/8 probability to have a duplicate. On the third throw you have a 2/8 probability to have a duplicate. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Well, I want an exact value for $P(X=3)$.  Hint:  You can read it off from the numbers you just produced.

Comment: Should it be 2/8 ?

Comment: I got it!! If X=3, that means 7/8 * 2/8 = 7/32. This added to the P(X=1) = 1/8 makes 11/32. 1- 11/32 = 21/31 which is the correct answer! Thanks :D

Comment: For an even easier approach, follow the suggestion from @Peter.  $P(X>3)$ is the probability that no duplicate is seen in the first three tosses.  But that's just $\frac 78\times \frac 68=\frac {21}{32}$.  No need to break out the $P(X=2)$ and $P(X=3)$ cases.